# Node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, predictionio, hbasestorage

When running PredictionIO on a local single node Hadoop (HortonWorks) I get the following error:

```
 Storage Backend Connections
  Verifying Meta Data Backend
  Verifying Model Data Backend
  Verifying Event Data Backend
  ERROR client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation - The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
  ERROR storage.Storage$ - Error initializing storage client for source HBASE
  ERROR storage.Storage$ - org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: The node /hbase is not in ZooKeeper. It should have been written by the master. Check the value configured in 'zookeeper.znode.parent'. There could be a mismatch with the one configured in the master.
 java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:313)
at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:311)
at io.prediction.data.storage.Storage$.sourcesToClientMeta(Storage.scala:90)
at io.prediction.data.storage.Storage$.getDataObject(Storage.scala:193)
at io.prediction.data.storage.Storage$.getDataObject(Storage.scala:178)
at io.prediction.data.storage.Storage$.getLEvents(Storage.scala:274)
at io.prediction.data.storage.Storage$.verifyAllDataObjects(Storage.scala:246)
at io.prediction.tools.Console$.status(Console.scala:1259)
at io.prediction.tools.Console$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Console.scala:646)
at io.prediction.tools.Console$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Console.scala:601)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
at io.prediction.tools.Console$.main(Console.scala:601)
at io.prediction.tools.Console.main(Console.scala)

Unable to connect to all storage backend(s) successfully. Please refer to error message(s) above. Aborting.
```

How should I configure HBase + Zookeepr on a local Hadoop installation?

Comment: Have you start hbase-master before hbase-regionserver? It seems the master isn't started or have some errors.

Comment: I start *all* services from HortonWorks web interface. Is it possible that it starts them in the wrong order?

Answer (score 1):

At Hbase folder /conf/hbase-site.xml, config or add:

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
  <value>YOUR ZOOKEEPER FOLDER</value>
</property>
```

For example:

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
  <value>/home/myname/zookeeper-3.4.6</value>
</property>
```